# using a value from the database in JIRA filter

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jql

We have a custom label in JIRA that we apply to our tasks with sprint label.
We have a table in our database that stores the start and end of each sprint cycle.
I want to add a filter to retrieve tasks in the current sprint.
My sql would look somthing like

```
select top 1 SprintLabel
from dbo.Sprint
where GETDATE() between StartDate and EndDate
```

and I would want my query to look something like

```
"Sprint Label" in (currentSprint()) AND Developer in (currentUser())
```

I have found how to create custom fields that get their values from the database but they can only be on the LHS of a comparison operator in the filter.